# Looping over specific values in PARI/GP

Tags: for-loop, vector, pari, pari-gp

I have a large collection of vectors, each of the form `[a,b,c,d]`.

For each vector, I want to return the result `[a,b,c,d,a+b^2+c^3+d^4]`. What would be the best way of doing this?

For example, say my vectors are `V = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12] ]`. Would the best way to do this be defining a function such as:

`test( W ) = for( i=1, #W, print( [ [W[i][1],W[i][2],W[i][3],W[i][4],W[i][1]+W[i][2]^2+W[i][3]^3+W[i][4]^4] ] ) )` ?

(Keeping in mind that in practice I will also have a larger collection of vectors)

This feels like a naive way of doing this, so is there a better way? In particular, is this the quickest way? Is there a better way to store my collection of vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use matrix to store the vector of vectors. Then just append the new column containing the sum of your exponentials. See the example:

```
V = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];  /* your vector of vectors */

M = matconcat([V[1]; V[2]; V[3]]);
M_log = log(M);

matconcat([M, M[,1] + exp(2*M_log[,2]) + exp(3*M_log[,3]) + exp(4*M_log[,4])])
> [1  2  3  4 288.00]
> [5  6  7  8 4480.00]
> [9 10 11 12 22176.00]
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, you can use `foreach` to iterate over a vector entries, then a multi-assignment `[a,b,c,d] = x` to assign a name to the entries' components as in your example. This yields

```
V = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]; 
foreach(V, x, my([a,b,c,d] = x); print([a,b,c,d, a+b^2+c^3+d^4]))
```